# How to avoid using "../" when webpage is located in subdirectory?

Tags: javascript, html, css, url

I am working on a static website as a web design project for college. It's a tech blog that contain mock articles. I'm storing the website in the root (these are pages like index.htm, news.html, reviews.html, etc). However, I want to avoid clutter for actual article pages. So I store these pages in a subdirectory called articles, example: "articles/article1.html".

Now I have to write two javascript files because of this. My two javascript files would do exactly the same thing except javascript file A is for all pages in the root and javascript file B is for all pages in the articles subdirectory. And that's because my javascript code accesses files in my website. That means I have to prepend "../" to all urls in js file B for my js to work. File A would not have "../" appended.

What can I do to only use 1 javascript file for my static website?

Comment: You might be looking for the [`<base href="http://www.domain.com/website-root/">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag? Note that this will also change all links that are relative.

Comment: Looks more like you're looking for absolute urls

Comment: I didn't get it, What is blocking you from having single file..? Can't you have a single js file in root, and a constant like `"./articles/"` which you can prepend while trying to access articles..?

Comment: Right now I am not using a domain name or htaccess. I'm not sure if that is useful info but I think thats why I dont know how to do absolute paths. Also I guess I could use the server address but would it be possible to test it without waiting for upload? In other words test my website offline?

Comment: TJ it is because html in root can not access files in ../ because that would mean go to the roots parent. So it would be parent/images  instead of parent/root/images

Comment: I tried looking at base href...does this only work if my website is hosted? Will this work for something not same but similar to <base href="index.html">, because I tried that before I asked here and it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prepend the URLs with `/`. This always take you to the root, so regardless of where the file is, you start the path with the root folder.

Like

```
img.src = "/Images/img1.jpg";
```

**NOTE**

This will not work if your site is running in a subfolder

Comment: @h2ooooooo - True. Thought that's not the case, taking from the OP's question, but I added the note.

Comment: Index is in root...will not be a problem. I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. I thought you meant subfolder of the root. Now I think you mean if index.html has a parent directory. I guess this method will work if you hosted the website or have htacess set up?

Comment: @poetryrocksalot - That will work the same, you just have to specify the folder, starting from the url root, like: `"/firstfolder/anything_else"`

Comment: Yup, this works. But there is catch. You have to either do this on a proper web host or on the localhost. .htacess is not required for this. It works when ran as the local host. But it does not work when simply running as an offline html file. I will have to start developing on the localhost. There are many problems previewing offline too, so might as well start doing it although I wish apache's config file is easier to setup.